# Invalid scope trying to add User.Read.All in V2.0 Microsoft Graph API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm working on an UWP app that uses Microsoft graph API v2.0 to query data from the user organization.

Currently i am able to authenticate using this url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/V2.0/authorize?
         client_id={MY_APP_CLIENTID}
         &redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob
         &response_type=code
         &scope=openid%20offline_access%20User.Read%20Contacts.Read
```

But i need to call WorkingWith API:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/workingWith
```

This requires the User.Read.All scope to be added to the authentication call. But every time i try to add it i get an "invalid scope value" page.

I tried to ser the scope both using User.Read.All & https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All with no luck.

I have my app registered in the new developer portal: `apps.dev.microsoft.com`.

Is there any extra step to use the User.Read.All scope in a mobile app or it is not allowed?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

After talking with several folks from MVPs list... seems the problem is, although you can authenticate the way i'm doing and use several APIs, Global Address List is heavily tied to AAD, so you need to go the way of registering your app on AAD and give it permissions there to being able to query WorkingWith... a reasonable alternative seems to be the `outlook.office.com` API `/me/contacts` that return the users contacts in the user private address folder...

Hope this at least helps others see the problem/solution easily :)